# how to draw ellipse over the jpanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel

I have three classes: CanvasPanel, Drawline and DrawRectangle.

- **CanvasPanel:** This is for handling all mouse event listener.
- **Drawline:** This is for drawing line on CanvasPanel.
- **DrawRectangle:** This is for drawing rectangle on CanvasPanel.

All three class are extending `JPanel` class.

Drag and drop of all component is going fine. But the problem is when I drag the line over the rectangle then line has been gone behind the rectangle. Can you give me the solution or give me some example, so I can understand how this is happening.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the components transparent by calling [setOpaque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setOpaque%28boolean%29)(false).